# How heavy is an orbital pogo stick?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, orbital-maneuver, design-alternative, mass, space-tug

Moving people from a A to B in space often requires a significant change in velocity, requiring propellant eating into the mass budget.

But most of this propellant is "wasted" in moving a fully facilitated *spacecraft*, not just the people aboard.

What if we got rid of the spacecraft? This is the concept of an orbital pogo stick. Cosmonauts can stay in their EVA suits for a couple of hours, fire up a minimal propulsion system, and check into a hotel at the other end.

**How "minimal" is such a minimal propulsion system?** It's a little rocket engine, tanks, some controls, restraints to <strike>prevent passengers from flailing around in terror</strike> provide comfort during the flight. How much could it be?

Some closely applicable studies are the one-man [Lunar Flying Vehicle](http://www.astronautix.com/l/lfvnorthamerican.html), dry mass without pilot of 141.8 kg, and its cousin the two-man [Lunar Escape System](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19700022470/downloads/19700022470.pdf) at 171.5 kg.

These would be a baseline, but the use case is different. A surface launch is different from a transfer in space.

There has also been some technological advances in the 50 years since these were considered. (The LESS report has a VHF transponder at 25 pounds!)

[image: LESS docking]

Comment: To have humans in orbit is expensive. I have a hard time imagining a purpose for this kind of solution. Except a tourist sightseeing of course. Even satellite inspection/repair would be easier to do without human hands-on.

Comment: If you send up a cosmonaut in a flying chair to go to an orbital station, you have to send up a second full spacecraft to bring them back down, if desired. If you send up a cosmonaut in a working spacecraft, they can use that spacecraft to come back down in. outside of  dramatic license in fiction, there's not currently a use case for going from one space station to another, or from space station to other orbiting satellite.

Comment: @notovny Current rewed spaceflight is limited to LEO shuttling, so I agree with you there.

Comment: You don’t need a full spacecraft to get out of orbit - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOOSE

Comment: I'd seriously consider some type of nav/guidance capability onboard the "pogo stick." When orbital mechanics come into play, things can get hazardous for the "pogo stick" riders, along with the destination vehicle...